# Apex trigger zero code coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Can anyone please help me to solve my issue. I have created apex trigger with test classes. I am not getting any error after test run but unable to getting any code coverage. Please check below is my apex trigger and test class.

```
            trigger getAllContacts on Scheme__c (after insert,after update) 
            {
                List<ANZSIC_Contact__c> acc = new List<ANZSIC_Contact__c>();
                for(Scheme__c scheme :trigger.new)
                {
                    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Underwriter').getRecordTypeId();
                    if(scheme.Account__c != null && scheme.Account__r.RecordTypeId== devRecordTypeId )
                    {
                        List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>();
                        con = [select Id,Email,Phone from contact where Account.Id =:scheme.Account__c];
                        for(Contact c:con)
                        {
                            acc = [select Id from ANZSIC_Contact__c where Contact__c =:c.Id and Scheme__c =:scheme.Id];
                            if(acc ==Null)
                            {
                                ANZSIC_Contact__c ac = new ANZSIC_Contact__c();
                                ac.Contact__c = c.Id;
                                ac.Scheme__c = scheme.Id;
                                ac.Email__c = c.Email;
                                ac.Phone__c = c.Phone;
                                acc.add(ac);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        insert acc;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The test class:

```
            @isTest(seeAllData=false)
            private class Test_getAllContacts
            {
                static testMethod void getAllContacts()
                {
                    test.startTest();
                    RecordType businessAccountRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND Name = 'Underwriter'];
                    Account acc = new Account();
                    acc.Name = 'Test Account';
                    acc.RecordTypeId = businessAccountRecordType.Id;
                    insert acc;Contact con = new Contact();
                    con.LastName = 'Test data';
                    con.AccountId = acc.Id;
                    con.Email ='n@yahoo.in';
                    con.Phone = '987654321';
                    insert con; Scheme__c  sh = new Scheme__c();
                    sh.Account__c = acc.Id; 
                    insert sh;

                      test.stopTest();
                }
            }
```

Comment: No coverage whatsoever ?

Comment: your Trigger is on Scheme__c object (on insert/update) and you are not even inserting or updating  Scheme__c record in your test method. You have to insert or update Scheme__c record in your test method to invoke Trigger code.

Comment: No 0% code coverage.

Comment: That line was deleted Please check my code again.

Comment: still 0% code coverage?

Comment: Yes. It's 0 % code coverage.

Comment: please add few debug statements in trigger code and check debug logs to see whether trigger code is getting invoked or not.

Answer (score -1):

You have to insert the test data for the Scheme__c object record in the test class.

It seems that in the trigger you are inserting ANZSIC_Contact__c object record as soon as the Account and contact gets inserted with the recordtype: Underwriter. What will happen you insert the scheme__c. What is the code coverage?

Please add debug statements in the trigger before the line : insert acc; so that you can check whether the trigger is getting invoked or not.

```
@isTest
        private class Test_getAllContacts
        {
            static testMethod void getAllContacts()
            {

                RecordType businessAccountRecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND Name = 'Underwriter'];
                Account acc = new Account();
                acc.Name = 'Test Account';
                acc.RecordTypeId = businessAccountRecordType.Id;
                insert acc;Contact con = new Contact();
                con.LastName = 'Test data';
                con.AccountId = acc.Id;
                con.Email ='n@yahoo.in';
                con.Phone = '987654321';
                test.startTest();
                insert con; Scheme__c  sh = new Scheme__c();
                sh.Account__c = acc.Id; 
                  test.stopTest();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems that from the trigger you are inserting ANZSIC_Contact__c object record as soon as the Account and contact gets inserted with the recordtype: Underwriter .  What will happen you you insert the scheme__c. What is the code coverage? Please add the debug statements in the trigger before the line : insert acc; so that you can check whether the trigger is getting invoked or not.